# Docker not exposing port when using command line

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I am trying to start an ASP.NET Core container hosting a website.
It does not exposes the ports when using the following command line

`docker run my-image-name -d -p --expose 80`

or

`docker run my-image-name -d -p 80`

Upon startup, the log will show :

`Now listening on: http://[::]:80`

So I assume the application is not bound to a specific address.

But **does work** when using the following docker compose file

```
version: '0.1'

services:
  website:
    container_name: "aspnetcore-website"
    image: aspnetcoredocker
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    expose:
      - '80'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure to pass all options (`-d -p 80`) to the docker command before naming the `image` as described in [the docker run docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/). The notation is:

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

So please try the following:

```
docker run -d -p 80 my-image-name
```

Otherwise the parameters are used as command/args inside the container. So basically running your entrypoint of the docker image with the additional params of `-d -p 80` instead of passing them to the docker command itself. So in your example the docker daemon is just not receiving the params `-d` and `-p 80` and thus not mapping the port to the host. You can also notice that by not receiving the `-d` the command runs in the foreground and you see the logs in your terminal.

Comment: Correct. I should be more attentive. Thank you.